# run different function for different element in array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose you had an array like this and corresponding function:

```
let myArray = ['foo','bar','zoomba','foo'];

doThings(myArray[1]);
```

And you wanted one function, to run one of three different functions based on whether the string argument was either 'foo','bar', or 'zoomba'.

```
function doThings(myInput) {
   if (myInput === 'foo'){
     // run a nested function related to 'foo'
   }
   else if (myInput === 'bar') {
     //run a nested function related to 'bar'
   } // etc etc
 }
```

Are we left with no other option than to string else if together, is there a better way to match different functions or codeblocks to what we might return from an array or even a key value pair?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name as a key:

```
function handle_foo() {}
function handle_bar() {}
function handle_zoomba() {}

var functions = {
    foo: handle_foo,
    bar: handle_bar,
    zoomba: handle_zoomba
};

function doThings(myInput) {
    var handle = functions[myInput];
    if (handle) {
        handle()
    }
}
```